# After downloading the Breach Compilation.torrent, how do I properly introduce new breach lists?

Tags: passwords

So I downloaded the Breach Compilation (the 1.4 billion usernames w/ respective passwords). When doing so, the friendly dev-like homies they are over @ github where the .torrent file for the latter is posted, were kind enough to implement a sort utility, among others (such as a lookup tool etc.).

just wondering how I add new breaches to the collection properly. Any help would be much obliged. Hopefully we're allowed to post links in here, not to sure on the rules yet so forgive me ahead of time if its a no-no.

the 1.4 billion breach list comp and tools can be found here:

```
     https://gist.github.com/scottlinux/9a3b11257ac575e4f71de811322ce6b3
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about crypto at all

Comment: I've checked the link and saw that there is already some kind of support, there.

Comment: Hey @MeirMaor, sorry about that... was definitely out of touch with the exact site I was on.